# What is known about this type of generalisation of de Rham cohomology?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, derham-cohomology

I will describe a certain generalisation of de Rham cohomology; things could be generalised further but I will stick to a concrete example. A $0$-double-form is a function on the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. Using $z,\bar{z}$ as coordinates, the $1$-double-forms are spanned by $\eth z$ and $\eth \bar{z}$, where

$$
\eth z = \mathrm{d}z\otimes\mathrm{d}z,\qquad \eth \bar{z} = \mathrm{d}\bar z\otimes\mathrm{d}\bar z.
$$

The $2$-double-forms are spanned by 
$$
\eth z\wedge \eth \bar{z}= \left(\mathrm{d}z\otimes\mathrm{d}z\right) \otimes \left(\mathrm{d}\bar z\otimes\mathrm{d}\bar z\right) - \left(\mathrm{d}\bar z\otimes\mathrm{d}\bar z\right) \otimes \left(\mathrm{d}z\otimes\mathrm{d}z\right).
$$

The wedge operator is here defined to have all the expected properties. We can use the double exterior derivative $\eth$ to go from a $p$-double-form to a $(p+1)$-double-form. In particular, if $C$ is a $0$-double-form and $K=K_{zz}\eth z + K_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}\eth \bar{z}$ is a $1$-double-form, we define

$$
\eth C = \partial_z\partial_z C \eth z + \partial_{\bar{z}}\partial_{\bar{z}} C \eth\bar{z}
$$
and
$$
\eth K = (\partial_z\partial_z K_{\bar{z}\bar{z}} - \partial_{\bar{z}}\partial_{\bar{z}} K_{zz})\eth z \wedge \eth \bar{z}.
$$
Clearly $\eth^2=0$. These notions can easily be extended to a higher dimensional space, or to triple-forms, quadruple-forms, and so on.

My question is about the general nature of this cohomology. Is it well studied, and if so what is it called? How well does Poincare's Lemma extend to this cohomology? Can we integrate double-forms? If so, what are the generalisations of things like Stokes' theorem?

Some background on why I am interested: gauge field theories are formulated in terms of forms, and it seems like general relativity might be able to be described in a similar way in terms of double-forms.

Comment: Do you mean $\partial z$ instead of $\partial_z$, or are your 1-forms differential operators? And since you always write $\partial_z$ and never $\partial_w$, is all the differentiation happening in one direction? But in case you mean $\partial z\otimes\partial w$ etc. and differentiation is $\partial\otimes\partial$ and $\bar\partial\otimes\bar\partial$, then your complex is not elliptic and therefore you cannot expect a Poincaré Lemma to hold.

Comment: I'm using $\partial_z$ to just mean a $1$-tensor, I suppose I could have written $\mathrm{d}z$ instead. My $1$-double-forms are symmetric $2$-tensors.

Comment: I have never seen this before.

Comment: So, by $\partial_z$ you actually mean the standard coordinate holomorphic vector field $\partial / \partial z$?

Comment: Yes that's right. Sorry if my notation is unclear.

Comment: It would be nice if you edited your question to make notation clear. You are working on $\mathbb C^2$, but all your differential operators involve only one coordinate $z$. Are you avoiding to write indices, or do you mean to differentiate in only one direction? Since you say you want to consider symmetric tensors all the time, all we can do here is to guess. But then any answer you get might be an answer to a different question altogether ...

Comment: I've edited the question. I'm not sure why I put $\mathbb{C}^2$, I meant $\mathbb{C}$, sorry about that

Comment: It seems to me that your definition for the $\eth$ operator is not coordinate invariant. In particular, $\partial_z \partial_z C \eth z \ne \partial_{z'} \partial_{z'} C \eth z'$. The difference will be proportional to $\partial^2 z'/\partial z^2$. I don't know whether this is by design, but it makes me suspicious of your statement that such formulas "can easily be extended to a higher dimensional space..." or even to a different coordinate system.

Comment: You are of course correct. Your objection can be cured by the use of covariant derivatives, but it seems that before asking this question I hadn't sorted it out properly in my own head first. I will do so and then edit.